# multiple column of products and quantity from orders table sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Order tables having multiple columns for products and their quantities accordingly, 
like prod1, prod2,prod3,prod4 for products and qty1,qty2,qty3,qty4. 
because for one order there may be more than 1 products and each product have different quantity like some customer may order 
two mobile 'samsung J1' 1 piece(quantity) and 'samsung s6' 2 pieces(quantity).

if i query on order table for a specific product like

```
select *
from order
where (prod1 like '%j1%' or prod2 like '%j1%' or
       prod3 like '%j1%' or prod4 like '%j1%' )
```

it will give me list of all 'j1' product's orders. in this way i can count the number of order's but i want to count the number of quantity also from each order.

but the problem is that i am not getting any idea how i should detect that 'j1' product is prod1 or prod2 or prod3 or prod4, because if i can check its prod2 
then i will count qty2 and if 'j1' is as prod4 then i will count qty4.

for example one order may have 'j1' as prod1 or prod2 or prod3 or prod4. from above quanry we can check 'j1' product exists in this order but how 
we can count that quantity also for each order because each order may have different number of quantity for each product.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: Fix your data structure and have an `OrderProducts` table with one row per product in each order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff nice suggestion i already have this in mind but currently new on this company's db so looking for a quick fix later i will go for this.

Comment: Too add on to the comment by @GordonLinoff, a relational table with repeating groups violates the first normal form database design principal. A data model that follows normalization principals is generally more robust, enforces data integrity, and easier to query. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gordon's comment. Your data model is flawed. What happens if a customer wants to order more than 4 different products? Ideally, your data table would have a setup resembling something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderLines
(
    OrderLinesID int IDENTITY -- Primary key
    , FK_OrderID int NOT NULL -- Foreign key to Order table
    , ProductID int NOT NULL -- Foreign key to Products table
    , Quantity int NOT NULL 
    , .... -- Any additional fields you want to add
)
```

That way, you can produce your intended results using something like the following:

```
SELECT
    ProductID
    , COUNT DISTINCT FK_OrderID -- Count orders containing selected product
    , SUM(QUANTITY) -- Amount of selected product sold in this order
FROM
    OrderLines
WHERE 
    ProductID = 1 -- Id for J1, from the Product Table
GROUP BY
    ProductID
```

(Please note this is pseudocode, and a minimalistic table design. In real life, you'd probably have a lot more details)